# merging inputs with embeddings and dense layer

Tags: python, keras

I have two inputs, x_a and x_b where x_a is a categorical variable (hence the embedding) and x_b which is a usual feature matrix. Basically I want to multiply x_b by a weights matrix W_b which is a `10x64` matrix so that I end up with a 64 dimensional output.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding, Merge

encoder_cc = Sequential()

# Input layer for countries(x_a)
encoder_cc.add(Embedding(cc_idx.max(),64))
# Input layer for triggers(x_b)
encoder_trigger = Sequential()
# This should effectively be <W_b>
encoder_trigger.add(Dense(64, input_dim=10, init='uniform'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([encoder_cc, encoder_trigger], mode='concat'))
```

Then I want to combine (merge) these two before I do the usual Neural net stuff. Except that I get the error:

```
Exception: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 1, 64), (None, 64)]
```

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Try to add Flatten() layer in the end of both models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Embedding layer is made to be used for sequences, it outputs then a tensor with 3D of shape `(None, sequence_length, embedding_size)` which is in your case `(None, 1, 64)` because your input is of length 1.

The way to correct this is either to add a `Flatten()` layer to your encoder_cc model as Stephan suggests, or add a `Reshape((64,))` after the embedding layer.
This will force the output shape to be `(None, 64)` and match the shape of the other model.

I hope this helps.